# My columns are not showing up in Safari (but they are in Chrome, Explorer, Firefox)?

Tags: html, css, safari, containers

Only the 1st and 3rd column is showing up so I'm assuming it has to do with the display. I looked at
possible solutions with class and display. I can't seem to find a way for it to show up. Is there
something I should be adding or removing? Thank you!

```
<div id="NameA" >
<div id="NameB">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="container" id="content-container1"> 
        <div class="col-md-3" id="name1"> 
           </div>
        <div class="col-md-3" id="name2" >              
           </div>
        <div class="col-md-3" id="name3" >
           </div>   
        <div class="col-md-3" id="name4">
           </div>
</div><!--/content-container-->
</div><!-- /row -->
</div><!-- /container -->
</div>
</div>

CSS
#NameA {width: 100%; position: absolute; bottom: 0px;}
#NameB {padding-top: 20px; background-color: #000;  height: 220px; width:100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this, as sometimes there is hidden code in before and after that breaks Safari:

```
.row:before, .row:after {display: none !important;}
```